# How to access $user_profile in page.tpl.php or $page in user-profile.tpl.php in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, theming, users

I need to change layout of a profile depending on user's field. So, I need to either include regions in `user-profile.tpl.php` or access `$user_profile` to test that field in `page.tpl.php`.

I've seen this done, but can't find it now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As for including regions in `user-profile.tpl.php` here how you do it.

In your custom theme add the following code to template.php file

```
function mytheme_preprocess_user_profile(&$variables) { 
  // List of all regions for the current theme
  foreach (system_region_list($GLOBALS['theme']) as $region_key => $region_name) {
    // Add content to $region variable
    if ($blocks = block_get_blocks_by_region($region_key)) {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = $blocks;
    }
    else {
      $variables['region'][$region_key] = array();
    }
  }
}
```

Then copy `user-profile.tpl.php` to your custom theme and then place the following code between any HTML tag.

```
print render($region['region_name']);
```

Comment: I need to re-check this, as this is what I have done, but all I've got was "Undefined variable $region" notice.

Comment: @Mołot do have `else` in your code?

Comment: actually, it worked after some more cache clears.