# Contextual Filters based on a certain field

Tags: views

Im having trouble setting up a universal view. I have a content type for s SERVICE the company will offer. This content type contains a field for CATEGORY (not a taxonomy term) of the service. Then I want to have a page for portfolio. There I will have a list of all the services again and after you click on any it will link to a page where it would filter references for each category. So here the uni view would be used. I know it would probably be easier to do using taxonomy, but Id like to have it this way if possible. I know how to set context.filter by taking value from URL, but here, the category does not go to URL but is in that CATEGORY field. Anyone could shed some light on how to achieve this?

Thanks for any insight

Comment: I would use taxonomy, because that's what they are for, but if you insist on not to use them, take a look at similar question [here](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/73414/16739)